# Element scrolls to left side automatically and element gets hidden when clicked on element

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

Selenium version: 2.44
OS:  Windows 7 (64 bit)
Browser: Firefox and IE-10

In My application there is a webpage where I fill several details , the webpage has several update buttons and and also a scroll bar. When I run the selenium script and at the time when selenium tries to scroll down and find an element at the mid page or bottom of the page , the page displaces its position to left. This in turn hides the element to be searched and the test run fails.This issue never occurs manually.

I think this issue occurs because of scrolling automatically and perform click action

My code performs actions like if(selenium.findElement(CreateOrgAuthRecordRadioButton).isSelected() && selenium.findElement(LocApproveRadioButton).isSelected()) 
    {
      selenium.checkRadioB‌utton(locOrgradioBtn,Consts.ELEMENT_XPATH);
      selenium.click(l ocOrgmasterBtn,Consts.‌​ELEMENT_XPATH);
    }

The HTML snippet is like

```
        <div class="orgLocInfoHeading clear b" id="orgLocDiv">
          Organization and Location
        </div>
        <div class="orgLocInfoBody  fl">
          <div class="orgDataAuth  fl">
           <div class="orgSelection fl">
            <table class="domTable"  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td>  <input type="radio"  class="approvedFlag" id="cborgApproved" name="orgRadio"></td>
                    <td>Organization Approved</td>
                  </tr>
                   <tr>
                    <td> <input type="radio"  id="cborgNeedinfo" name="orgRadio"></td>
                    <td>Need more info for Org Auth</td>
                  </tr>
             </table>

              <div class="FormFieldContainer  noMargin clear" style="width:190px;">
                    <div class="FormElementLabelContainer lblOrgNamePOR dInline fl">
                         <label> </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="FormElementContainer font12 fl dInline">
                     <div class="FormElementBorderContainer">
                            <div id="orgStatus"></div>
                     </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Please share the HTML snippet of the element and also code that you've worked upon so far. Help us help you out.. Thanks. :)

Comment: Can you please elaborate and if you can add the code snippet that will be helpful too..

Comment: My code performs actions like if(selenium.findElement(CreateOrgAuthRecordRadioButton).isSelected() && selenium.findElement(LocApproveRadioButton).isSelected())  {selenium.checkRadioButton(locOrgradioBtn,Consts.ELEMENT_XPATH);selenium.click(locOrgmasterBtn,Consts.ELEMENT_XPATH);}
The HTML snippet is like<br/><div class="fl OrgInfoSection authDetailsContainer">
  <div class="orgNameDetails cmnBodyStyle fl">
   <div class="orgNamePOR fl  padBot10">
 <div class="FormFieldContainer b font12 noMargin fl noPadding clear">

Comment: Please put the above code(s) in your question in proper format.. It's not understandable putting it up here in the comments.

Comment: Added the code and the snippet in the Question. @Subh